# Как задать для моего кода минимальную версию PHP, на котором он может работаь?

Tags: php

Перерыл весь интернет, но так и не нашел вообще ничего по этой теме.

Как я могу в коде своего сайта проверять версию установленного на сервере PHP и выкидывать ошибку, если она меньше, скажем, версии 7.2?

Answer (score 2):

```
phpversion ([ string $extension ] ) : string
```

Возвращает строку с номером версии текущего PHP-интерпретатора или расширения.
Если задан аргумент extension, phpversion() вернет версию этого расширения или FALSE, если информации о версии нет или расширение в данный момент не включено.

С версии PHP 5.2.7 и выше также доступны константы `PHP_VERSION_ID`, `PHP_MAJOR_VERSION`, `PHP_MINOR_VERSION`.

В версиях ниже 5.2.7 можно поступить так:

```
if (!defined('PHP_VERSION_ID')) {
    $version = explode('.', PHP_VERSION);
    define('PHP_VERSION_ID', ($version[0] * 10000 + $version[1] * 100 + $version[2]));
    define('PHP_MAJOR_VERSION',   $version[0]);
    define('PHP_MINOR_VERSION',   $version[1]);
    define('PHP_RELEASE_VERSION', $version[2]);

    // и так далее ...
}
```

Comment: Как-то очень странно работает эта PHP_VERSION_ID. Почему она возвращает версию 70402 для версии 7.4.2? Откуда берутся нули и что они значат? Вместо точек ставятся?

Comment: Или нули оставили для случаев типа 7.4.11?

Comment: @anme верно, так и есть. Для десятков минорных и релизных версий.